# Python 3 with binary numbers

Tags: python

I want to write a function that returns a string representing the binary number after subtraction of 1. I'm stuck with the case 101,100 ... (I have to write the code without using the functions int() and bin() )

I wrote this :

```
def dec(bin):

  n = len(bin)   
  for i in range(n):

         if bin == '1' 
             result = '0'   
           break        
         else:  
           if bin.count(0)= 0:  
               res = bin[1:]+'0'
```

and here I don't have ideas how to continue, I'd be happy for help!

Answer (score 0):

I would cast to `int()` then do the subtraction, then `return bin(ans).replace("0b","")`

Comment: I have to work without int() and bin() functions :( , thanks!

Comment: Oh ok. Either way, would reccommend renaming the variable in your code, just out of good practice (bin)